# Show image based on selected category in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have menu.html page, in that page I have categories like Environment, Noise, Pollution... etc. I have subcategories for each category. Based on the selection of Category and subcategory, I have to show different image and different font color in my next page...

Any ideas/suggestions for that in HTML/JavaScript ....

Thanks
Kumar

Comment: You should add more details to your question like what you've tried so far or any fiddle share it here.

Comment: It seems you don't know much about HTML/javascript. just don't be nervous :). Try searching on google for your solution. you will get many solutions out there..

Comment: Can u post your code ?So that we help you ...

Answer (score 0):

what about css classes? You can give the specific classes a font-color and background-image.

Answer (score 0):

If you're linking to another page, you can add query string to the `URL` and manipulate it from the second page.

```
<a href="page.html?font=red&image=pollusion">Pollusion</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeImage(){
        var selectBox = document.getElementById("selectbox");
        var selectedValue = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
        document.getElementById("img").src = selectedValue + ".png";
    }
</script>
```

You can check the value of the selected  with `selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].innerHTML` too. That will make it easier if you have a lot of options and do not want to set the value of everything.

If the images on your server have the same names as the value of each option, you don't even need to use a if statement. However, if the images are in different places or have different names/extensions, you can set the code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeImage(){     
        var selectBox = document.getElementById("selectbox");
        var selectedValue = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
        var img = document.getElementById("img");
        if (selectedValue == "html"){
            img.src = "images/html.png";
        } else if (selectedValue == "css"){
            img.src = "images/css.jpeg";
        }
    }
</script>
```